# Not all links work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigationbar

I am coding a website and I have noticed that in the navigation bar some links work some don't.

I have realized that the groups of link that word have a different css code and if I remove it then the other ones will work but the others will not show up of course. I have tried so many things but nothing seems to work.

All I want is a group of links to the left of the bar and the rest to the right all of them working of course, here's the code that I have:

```
<!-- Create navigation bar-->
        <style>
            #TopBar{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:40px;
   background-color:#181818;
}
            </style>         
            <div id="TopBar"></div>     
        <!-- Create Page Links -->
        <style>
        ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white; 
    position: absolute; 
    font-family: sans-serif;        
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 163px;      
}
        </style>
        <style>
        al {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white; 
    position: absolute; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 1028px;
        }
        </style>
<style>
        li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;        
}
        </style>
        <style>
            a{color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration:none;   
            }
        </style>
        <ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Cos'è</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Chi Siamo</a></li>
</ul>
        <al>
            <li><a href="">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
        </al>
```

Hope someone can help me figuring this out soon.

Comment: why don't you place your CSS in a separate css file ? Also you have empty hrefs so you need to fill those URLs too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your CSS to this,

```
al {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
```

as you can see `padding-left:1028px;` is replaced with `right:0;` . because it was resulting in overlapping the left links. That's why click was not possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know what was wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

`<al>` is not an **HTML element** and that is why it isn't showing in the browser. Perhaps you meant `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Answer (score 0):

Man. Your code is messed up. Try to avoid having multiple styles in your html file. One to three may be okay. But after that you should definitely use an external stylesheet file — this is actually the case when you plan to release your code. So if this is for testing try to use this kind of layout — also it makes it easy to copy and paste it later.

```
-------
Head
- meta's
- style
-------
Body
-------
```

Then as already mentioned by some people here, `<al>` is not a valid HTML tag. I guess you meant `<ul>`.

Your links 'news' and so on will not work because `href=""` is empty you have to put something in. If e.g. your news HTML is in the same folder you can use

```
<a href="news.html">News</a>
```

If you want your second ul (unordered list) with different attributes you should add classes and ids — what most people never do unfortunately. In this case you should use an id. Try to learn this on your own first with sites like w3school. If you still need help then show us some code and we will help you but it is actually easy as hell.